# What's the difference between javax.persistence.Id and org.springframework.data.annotation.Id?

Tags: java, spring-data, jpa

I'd be interested whether there is the difference between `javax.persistence.Id` and `org.springframework.data.annotation.Id`.

1. If Spring has created that annotation only for support the JPA annotation, then why?
2. Does `org.springframework.data.annotation.Id` have another [additional] purpose?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

`org.springframework.data.annotation.Id` is currently used by Spring to support mapping for other non relational persistence databases or frameworks that do not have a defined common persistence API like JPA. So, it is normally used when dealing with other spring-data projects such as spring-data-mongodb, spring-data-solr, etc.

`javax.persistence.Id` is the annotation defined by JPA for all its implementations. Have in mind JPA only applies for management of relational data.

Comment: I get that you wouldn't be able to use the javax ID for non-relational persistence, but can I  use the Spring ID on a basic relational JPA entity? 

Basically is it safe to basically always use the Spring ID?

Comment: So if my project use relational database only, it would be ok to use `javax.persistence` ?

Comment: Great answer, straight to the point.

Comment: JPA will only recognize javax.persistence.Id (now jakarta.persistence.Id). Otherwise it will throw an exception: 
Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' ... Entity has no identifier (every '@Entity' class must declare or inherit at least one '@Id' or '@EmbeddedId' property)