# Cannot instantiate DTO Projection in Spring Data

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-projections

I am trying to return a custom object `RecordData` from my repository class, but it tries to instantiate my main `Record` class. I've tried using `Interface Projections`, but the result is the same.

```java
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.PrimaryKey;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.Table;

@Table
public class Record {

    public record RecordData(long created_at, double value) {

    }

    @PrimaryKey
    private final long sensor_id;

    private final long created_at;

    private final double value;

    public Record(long sensor_id, long created_at, double value) {
        this.sensor_id = sensor_id;
        this.created_at = created_at;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public long getSensorId() {
        return sensor_id;
    }

    public long getCreatedAt() {
        return created_at;
    }

    public double getValue() {
        return value;
    }

}
```

```java
@Repository
public interface RecordsRepository extends CassandraRepository<Record, String> {

    @Query("SELECT created_at, value FROM record WHERE sensor_id = ?0 and created_at > ?1")
    List<Record.RecordData> findBySensorIdAndCreatedAt(Long sensorId, Long createdAt);

}
```

**Stack-trace:**

```java
org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate com.example.mainservice.models.entities.Record using constructor public com.example.mainservice.models.entities.Record(long,long,double) with arguments null,300,0.0

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter sensor_id must not be null!
```

Comment: What is `@PrimaryKey` annotation? I think that `@Id` should be used, and probably you have `null` value stored in db for `sensor_id`.

Comment: @birca123, it's imported from `org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.PrimaryKey`. I've tried using `javax.persistence.Id` as well, but I do receive the same error. Also, I have no `null` values stored in DB. As I understand, it returns `createdAt` and `value` and tries to instantiate `Record` class, passing `null` in `Record` constructor, because it was not returned.

Comment: Try to use `org.springframework.data.annotation.Id` instead of `javax.persistence.Id`- https://stackoverflow.com/a/39644765/14394219

Comment: @artiomi, using `org.springframework.data.annotation.Id` still throws the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Make these changes in your code:

```
    @Entity
    public class Record {

    public record RecordData(long created_at, double value) {

    }

    @Id
    private final long sensor_id;

    private final long created_at;

    private final double value;

    public Record(long sensor_id, long created_at, double value) {
        this.sensor_id = sensor_id;
        this.created_at = created_at;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public long getSensorId() {
        return sensor_id;
    }

    public long getCreatedAt() {
        return created_at;
    }

    public double getValue() {
        return value;
    }

}
```

And

```
@Repository
public interface RecordsRepository extends CassandraRepository<Record, String> {

    @Query("SELECT r.created_at, r.value FROM Record r WHERE r.sensorId = :sensorId and r.createdAt > :createdAt")
    List<Record.RecordData> findBySensorIdAndCreatedAt(@Param("sensorId") Long sensorId, @Param("createdAt") Long createdAt);

}
```

Comment: Hi, this returned me the same error. Also, you did not provide any imports, but I think you use `@Id` and `@Table` from `javax.persistence`.

Comment: can you share the error and yes i used javax.persistance

Comment: It's the same as in my post - `Failed to instantiate com.example.mainservice.models.entities.Record using constructor public com.example.mainservice.models.entities.Record(long,long,double) with arguments null,300,0.0

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter sensor_id must not be null!`

Comment: have you inserted the data after that or you using the same data

Comment: I am performing a test, thus the data is always deleted and instantiated from new.

Comment: are you inserting the id or not, or you want to insert it on its own

Comment: ```@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)private final long sensor_id;```

Comment: try this in your code this will auto-increment the  id

Comment: I am always providing `sensorId` and it should not be generated. All I understand it does not return my custom object `RecordData` and tries to instantiate `Record` and it has nothing to do with `Id`, whether it's generated by auto-increment or whatever.

Comment: change record with Record in query as this is your class name and try

Comment: i have changed the code and query both try that

Comment: Hi, when I add `@Entity`, I get `A bean with that name has already been defined in com.example.mainservice.repositories.RecordsRepository defined in @EnableCassandraRepositories declared on CassandraRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableCassandraRepositoriesConfiguration and overriding is disabled.` I do have @EnableCassandraRepositories and -overriding=true in properties.

Comment: @EnableCassandraRepositories try after removing this

Comment: I have tried with & without `@EnableCassandraRepositories` and/or `-overriding=true` in properties, still the same error.

Comment: try changing this CassandraRepository<Record, long>

Comment: I've just resolved by adding empty argument constructor in my `Record` class. :)

Comment: good bro, well done and sorry i couldn't help

Answer (score 1):

Try making your table an entity so that it retrieves the data and map it with your object.

As a class which should be persisted in a database it must be annotated
Use javax.persistence library for imports

User @Id as this will make your id a primary key as per JPA

Add the @Entity annotation in your table like below and there is no need to write @Table if you are not giving a custom name to your table as @Table is used to name your table. It is stored as that name in your database

```
@Entity  //insert here
public class Record {

public record RecordData(long created_at, double value) {

}

@Id
private final long sensor_id;
....
}
```

Try this it should work

Comment: And yes you should change the table name in query to match with your Entity i.e

Record should be in capital                      
@Query("SELECT created_at, value FROM record WHERE sensor_id = ?0 and created_at > ?1")
    List<Record.RecordData> findBySensorIdAndCreatedAt(Long sensorId, Long createdAt);

Comment: When I add `@Entity`, I get `The bean 'recordsRepository', defined in com.example.mainservice.repositories.RecordsRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration, could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in com.example.mainservice.repositories.RecordsRepository defined in @EnableCassandraRepositories declared on CassandraRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableCassandraRepositoriesConfiguration and overriding is disabled.` I do have `@EnableCassandraRepositories` and `-overriding=true` in properties.

Comment: Okay in that case you do not have to use `@Entity` . Just use `@Table` in top  of Record class 
And use the `@PrimaryKey` annotation which you were using before.
Just change the 2nd Generic type in your repository interface to **"long"** as it should be same as your data type for primary key. 


`@Repository
public interface RecordsRepository extends CassandraRepository<Record, Long> {
`
and just one more thing , in your query mention Record same as table name in java as it only checks the name given in java file not sql

Let me know if this doesn't works

Comment: Resolved my problem by adding empty argument constructor (:

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
@Entity
@Table(name="record")
public class Record {

    public record RecordData(long created_at, double value) {

    }

    @Id
    private final long sensor_id;

    private final long created_at;

    private final double value;

    public Record(long sensor_id, long created_at, double value) {
        this.sensor_id = sensor_id;
        this.created_at = created_at;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public long getSensorId() {
        return sensor_id;
    }

    public long getCreatedAt() {
        return created_at;
    }

    public double getValue() {
        return value;
    }

}
```

```
@Repository
public interface RecordsRepository extends CassandraRepository<Record, String> {

    @Query("SELECT created_at, value FROM record WHERE sensor_id = :sensor_id and created_at > :created_at")
    List<Record.RecordData> findBySensorIdAndCreatedAt(@Param("sensor_id")Long sensorId,@Param("created_at") Long createdAt);

}
```

Comment: Adding `@Entity` throws me `A bean with that name has already been defined in com.example.mainservice.repositories.RecordsRepository defined in @EnableCassandraRepositories declared on CassandraRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableCassandraRepositoriesConfiguration and overriding is disabled.` I do have @EnableCassandraRepositories and -overriding=true in properties.

Comment: so just use @Table annotation and Primary key  annotation instead of Id

Comment: I was missing empty argument constructor after all.

Comment: Ok so add @NoargsConstructor

Comment: If my code helped you in any way just give a tick

Answer (score 0):

I should think having a separate class would help

```
public class RecordData {
    private Long createdAt;
    private Double value;
    public RecordData(Long createdAt, Double value) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
        this.value = value;
    }
}

@Repository
public interface RecordsRepository extends CassandraRepository<Record, String> {

    @Query("SELECT new RecordData(r.created_at, r.value) FROM Record r WHERE r.sensorId = :sensorId and r.createdAt > :createdAt")
    List<RecordData> findBySensorIdAndCreatedAt(@Param("sensorId") Long sensorId, @Param("createdAt") Long createdAt);
}
```

Comment: This throws me `no viable alternative at input 'RecordData' (SELECT [new] RecordData...)`

Comment: I have updated to include r.value passed to projection constructor, also you need to use the fully qualified name of the projection 'new com.mypackage.RecordData(r.created_at, r.value)'

Comment: This throws the same: `Query; CQL [SELECT new com.example.mainservice.models.entities.RecordData(r.created_at, r.value) FROM Record r WHERE r.sensorId = ? and r.createdAt > ?]; line 1:11 no viable alternative at input 'com' (SELECT [new] com...);`

Answer (score 0):

All I needed to add was an empty argument constructor.

```java
public Record() {
}
```